# Should I confront the owner of the business (he hired me) about my supervisor lying about my performance and subsequently firing me?

Tags: termination, failure

I was hired as office manager for a kitchen & bath design company.  During the interview, I was very candid about what experience I had, as well as what I didn't know about the position, i.e. the design program.

We all agreed, (the owner, the designer and myself) that the designer would train me on the design program along with my duties as office manager. I did not get the program training from the designer.  I got online training from the program itself.

**After five weeks, the designer fired me** due to not knowing the program, as well as other aspects that weren't even in my job description.

She also told the owner I had lost customers which was completely false.  In fact, she had lost a major project that I had found and confronted her with.

The week prior to her firing me, she and the owner had praised me for all of the good work I had done. The owner had given me the go ahead to get the program training from another business that used the same program and who he was friends with.

I relayed this to the designer, along with the project that was lost and was subsequently fired the next day.  I was, in fact, doing a great job and was becoming more and more knowledgeable in all aspects of my job.

I was in line to become a designer along with the current designer as we were getting very busy with projects.

I believe she fired me in order to save face over the lost project.

I am so upset about losing a job that I had come to love.

Should I confront the owner?

Comment: What do you hope to gain by confronting the owner?

Comment: Other than venting, what do you aim to accomplish here?

Comment: Who exactly fired you? The designer? Did they have the authority to do so?

Comment: Confronting the owner will not change the situation. The owner will always go with keeping the person who is currently doing the work. So, what would you want to happen?

Comment: Where you given an official reason (in writing even?). Do you live in a juristiction where a notice period is common?

Comment: It seems that the only resolution that would make any meaningful difference to you would be firing the designer and hiring you back. Does it seem achievable? If not, confronting the owner is just a waste of your time and energy. AKA "pick battles that you can win".

Comment: I agree that "confronting" the owner has very little upside. However, you say you love this job. What you might want to do to make the best of this situation is have a discussion with the owner and see if they are willing to write you a recommendation or connect you with someone else in the industry so you can get employment in a similar role to the one you lost.

Comment: At the very least telling the owner what happened is going to make it harder for the designer to pull this stunt again. And it's not like you have anything to lose. But I would *inform* the owner about what happened rather than *confronting* them.

Comment: The designer fired me.  The owner left that up to her since she was the one who had a problem with me.  I agree that confronting him would get me nowhere as he would not fire the current designer.  I really appreciate your suggestion InBedded16.  I have found a posting for a designer with like requirements.  I will reach out to the owner for a recommendation.  Thank you all for your feedback!

Comment: You're asking if you should do something, something that likely won't help you at all.  The answer is "no".  Save your energy doing stuff that helps you.  Also, there are always two sides to each story.  The company gave you five weeks for your training.  Sure, they said a person would train you, but then they offered you (effectively) an online class.  Somehow after those five weeks, you didn't know enough to get the job done, in their minds you might have been fired for breaking your promise to them, to "learn the program."  How you learn it is far less important than "can you do the job?"

Comment: Sounds like a case of you embarrassed your boss, they were upset about that fact, and fired you for it. Sadly, that’s allowed, the good news is you now have additional experience and training for your next job. You can confront the owner, but what is the end goal, even if they reversed the firing decision you would then have to work with the individual who fired you.

Comment: I agree DONALD, she was embarrassed. She claims I was fired for not knowing or doing things that were not even in my job description or mentioned in my interview.  Hopefully, I can use this experience to my advantage!